# Objective C not going in if else statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have this piece of code

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(open:(NSString *)path invocation:(nonnull NSNumber *)invocationId
    options:(NSDictionary *)options)
{
    NSString *displayName = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"displayName"]];
    DyteFile *file = [[File alloc] initWithPath:path title:displayName];

    QLPreviewController *controller = [[CustomQLViewController alloc] initWithFile:file identifier:invocationId];
    controller.delegate = self;

    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    BOOL canOpenFile = [QLPreviewController canPreviewItem:file];
    if(canOpenFile) {
        [[RNFileViewer topViewController] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
            [weakSelf sendEventWithName:OPEN_EVENT body: @{@"id": invocationId}];
        }];
    } else {
        [weakSelf sendEventWithName:OPEN_EVENT body: @{@"id": invocationId, @"error": @"File not supported"}];
    }
} //last line
```

Here the code doesn't execute if-else statement i.e, it goes till this line

```
 BOOL canOpenFile = [QLPreviewController canPreviewItem:file];
```

and then to the last line i.e

```
} //last line
```

any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: how did you confirm it's getting skipped?

Comment: Add a NSLog inside each branch of the if to be sure. Debug might not be reliable with step positions.